# Cannot bind port on haproxy

Tags: haproxy

I'm trying to bind multiple certs on different ports but I'm getting the following error:

```
[ALERT] 308/144418 (17671) : Starting frontend https_in: cannot bind socket [10.12.61.12:444]
```

This is the config

```
frontend https_in
        bind 10.12.61.11:80
        bind 10.12.61.11:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/domain1.com.pem
        bind 10.12.61.12:444 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/sub.domain1.com.pem

        mode tcp

        acl domain_site1 hdr(host) -i site.domain.com
        use_backend bk_domain1 if domain_site1

        acl domain_site2 hdr(host) -i site.sub.domain.com
        use_backend bk_domain1 if domain_site2

backend bk_domain1
        balance leastconn

        server node1 10.0.20.16:80 check
        server node2 10.0.20.18:80 check
```

Netstat doesn't show anything listening on port 444 so I'm not sure why this is failing.

This is output of `ip addr`

```
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000 
  link/ether 00:15:5d:14:91:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 10.12.61.55/24 brd 10.12.61.255 scope global dynamic eth0
    valid_lft 691041sec preferred_lft 691041sec 
  inet 10.12.61.11/32 scope global eth0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet 10.12.61.12/32 scope global eth0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe14:9107/64 scope link
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: could you specify your distribution and version

Comment: Can you post the output of `ip addr`?

Comment: In addition to @GregL: Is the ip `10.12.61.12` in the fourth line of your config correct?

Comment: I'm running Centos 7 with haproxy 1.5.4

Comment: @GregL
ip addr:
 
eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:14:91:07 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.12.61.55/24 brd 10.12.61.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 691041sec preferred_lft 691041sec
    inet 10.12.61.11/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.12.61.12/32 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe14:9107/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

Comment: @AM74: Did you found a solution for this?

Comment: yes, I changed distro to debian and version of haproxy to 1.6 and worked fine

Comment: I'm running haproxy 1.6 on Debian now and it's working.

Comment: @AM74: Alright, great...still I'm curious, what caused the error.

Answer (score -3):

You might have to update the ports config on your server

/etc/services

```
snpp            444/tcp                         # Simple Network Paging Protocol
snpp            444/udp                         # Simple Network Paging Protocol
```

to

```
https           444/tcp                         # http protocol over TLS/SSL
https           444/udp                         # http protocol over TLS/SSL
https           444/sctp                        # http protocol over TLS/SSL
```

Comment: Tried that but still can't bind to port 444.